# Python: Unpack call_args_list from unittest.mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

i would like to unpack the arguments of a mocked method. I have a mocked subscriber which is called by the code under test and i would like to verify the invocation of the notify() method.

```
class Subscriber:
    def notify(self, event):
        pass
```

I'm using the following snippet to unpack the arguments and verify two invocations:

```
calls= self.subscriber.notify.call_args_list
event1 = calls[0][0][0]
event2 = calls[1][0][0]

assert_that(event1, instance_of(CreatedEvent))
assert_that(event1.file.name, equal_to("foo.txt"))
```

But the two lines to unpack the events are very clumsy and far away from readable code.
Does somebody know a better approach to unpack the arguments?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What will you do with `event1` and `event2`? I don't understand...

Comment: Updated the question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to assert the same thing for events in each call, then using a simple for loop might help:

```
for call in calls:
    event = call[0][0]
    assert_that(event, instance_of(CreatedEvent))
    assert_that(event.file.name, equal_to("foo.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert_has_calls`

```
calls.assert_has_calls(call(ANY, ...), call(...))
```